# How to add child to children list conditionally?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a `ListTile` where i want have 2 childs for subtitle. The child should be added only if not null.

```
 ListTile(
      title: Text(attachment.title),
      subtitle: Row(
        children: [
          Text(attachment.prop1), //Add only if prop1 is not null. How??
          Text(attachment.prod2), //Add only if prop2 is not null. How??
        ],
      ),
```

I can do it easily by writing a functions getChildren and then using the following.

```
ListTile(
      title: Text(attachment.title),
      subtitle: Row(
        children: getChildren()
        ,
      ),
```

Was wondering if there is some inline way like the fist approach to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ternary operator.

[condition == true ? if true add widget-1 : if false add widget-2,]

In your case, you can use ternary operator like this,

```
[
  attachment.prop1 != null ? Text(attachment.prop1) : Container(), 
  attachment.prop2 != null ? Text(attachment.prod2) : Container(),
]
```

Note: You have to pass an empty Container() widget for 'else' cases if you want to follow my approach. Otherwise your app will throw error because Flutter does not support null widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional ternary operators in Lists

```
 ListTile(
  title: Text(attachment.title),
  subtitle: Row(
    children: [
      prop1 == null ? Text(attachment.prod2) : Text(attachment.prop1),
    ],
  ),
```